# SQL Server 2016 with Azure Blob Container , nvarchar(max) is not supported for external tables?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create external table as it described in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652315.aspx
using following structure:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.Blob2 (  
        ID int NOT NULL,   
        Description nvarchar(max) NULL,   
        Title nvarchar(max)  NULL
)  
WITH (LOCATION='/Blob/',   
        DATA_SOURCE = AzureStorage,  
        FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat 
);
```

and getting error:

```
Msg 46518, Level 16, State 12, Line 49
The type 'nvarchar(max)' is not supported with external tables.
```

Am I'm missing something? I'm seeing that in documentation for external tables nvarchar/string/text in the list
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935021.aspx

Is there any chance that I can store text data in that container?